# How to solve ora-01841 in oracle sql during change my date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have timestamp with timezone.
for example 2023-02-28T03:34:11.249+03:30
I change my date with

```
To_char(to_timestamp_tz('column_name','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM'),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS','NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN') FROM TBL
```

I get error ora-01841:(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
How can I solve it?

I'm supposed to have some data ( year) not fixed to my formula.
ps: my column_name datatype is varchar2() so I have to write 'column_name' not "column_name".

Thanks

Comment: `'column_name'` is not a valid date. Did you mean `"column_name"`?

Comment: Apart from what @markalex said, what is COLUMN_NAME's **datatype**? Is it a VARCHAR2? If so, then (some) values stored within don't have YEAR where you expect it, and its values can't fit into what Oracle expects.

Comment: Obviously, you need to solve this by providing *(full) year between -4713 and +9999, and not 0*. Please find an erroneous date and then post it as a sample data in the question. To find such a date you may use `select ... from tablename where validate_conversion(column_name as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM') = 0`. See [`VALIDATE_CONVERSION`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD)

Comment: The datatype of my column is varchar2 but the format is like timestamp with timezone. If I use "column_name" instead of single qout, I have error "invalid number" @markalex

Comment: **a)** "... but the format is like timestamp with timezone" - that's what you think, but Oracle disagrees. **b)** "... instead of single quotes" - remove quotes entirely, unless you created table using lower letter case end enclosed that column name into double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `'column_name'` is a string literal and is not an identifier. You either want an unquoted identifier `column_name` or a quoted identifier `"column_name"` (with double quotes, not single, and this would be case-sensitive) or, if you do want to use a string literal then provide a valid timestamp string `'2023-02-28T03:34:11.249+03:30'`.

With an unquoted identifier, your code works:

```sql
SELECT To_char(
         to_timestamp_tz(
           column_name,
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM'
         ),
         'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS',
         'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN'
       ) as persion_ts
FROM   TBL
```

If you have invalid timestamp strings in the table then, from Oracle 12, you can use `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` to handle invalid values:

```sql
SELECT To_char(
         to_timestamp_tz(
           column_name
           DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM'
         ),
         'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS',
         'NLS_CALENDAR=PERSIAN'
       ) as persion_ts
FROM   TBL
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2J3m6C4-)

Comment: The datatype of my column is varchar2 but the format is like timestamp with timezone. If I use "column_name" instead of single qout, I have error "invalid number"

Comment: @mojgan The fiddle in the answer shows it working with unquoted identifiers and [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QXFXMDMx) shows it working with quoted identifiers. If it is not working for you then you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75875220/edit) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the complete query you are using so we can see what is producing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the wrong usage of the single-quoted string 'column_name', as pointed out by the colleagues, I'd recommend to use default null on conversion error in order to see what is wrong in your data. Something as below:

```sql
with tb as (  
  select to_timestamp_tz(column_name default null on conversion error, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM') c1, 
    column_name
  from x_table /* whatever your table name is*/
)
select *
from  tb
where c1 is null;
```